# Selective Rendering in Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

Is it possible to only render a single div (or using any selector) in puppeteer?
example: there's a lot of information on my page and I want to screenshot only a part of it, a div, currently I use the `clip` option of the screenshot api
but is there a way I can screen shot by specifying a selector?

Comment: Perhaps use [page.$](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.10.0&show=api-pageselector) to get an ElementHandle, then use [elementHandle.screenshot](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.10.0&show=api-elementhandlescreenshotoptions) to take a screenshot of the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many cool examples [ElementHandle.screenshots tests](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/2275c3c0c801d42514d6de127b9b1537d20356a9/test/screenshot.spec.js#L128), e.g.:

```js
await page.setViewport({width: 500, height: 500});
await page.goto(server.PREFIX + '/grid.html');
await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy(50, 100));
const elementHandle = await page.$('.box:nth-of-type(3)');
const screenshot = await elementHandle.screenshot();
```